# Convolutional coding that payload length does not change

Tags: digital-communications, channelcoding, communication-standard

This is the question about [Sigfox radio specification](https://build.sigfox.com/sigfox-device-radio-specifications#).

The stack:
[image]

Specifically, in Section 3.10 of the specification, we have a convolutional coding (after CRC) with three possible polynominals.

I am wonder whether really error correcting code (ECC) because the output and the input lengths are identical (Figure 3-6 in the specification, or see below).

[image]

The question is that if this is ECC, could anyone tell me what is the code rate? And if this is not ECC, what is its role?

Comment: Consider the possibility that there is a typo in the figure. They are apparently using a $(3,1)$ _systematic_ convolutional code with generator matrix $[1,1+x+x^2, 1+x^2]$ and so the coded UL-PHY-CONTENT should read "$240$ to $528$" or "$240$ to $536$" bits if the trailing tail of 6 bits (caused by the emptying of the code buffer) is included.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes it should. In fact I got the answer. The output should be 240 to 528 bits, but they are divided into three frames (three UL-PHY-CONTENT). That's where the ECC are implemented and this is an classic convolutional code. The specification is not clear at all.